# Commons XMLConfiguration and schema validation?

Tags: java, xml, xsd-validation, apache-commons-config

I using Apache Commons XMLConfiguration for my configuration. Now I need a schema based validation. But I have problems to add my xsd to the XMLConfiguration. The xsd is locateded in the application jar file.

If I use methods from Java SE the validation runs without problems:

```
private void checkSchema(final Path path) 
        throws SAXException, ParserConfigurationException, IOException
{
    final URL urlXsd = getClass().getResource(ConfigMain.SCHEMA_RESOURCE_PATH);
    final SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    final Schema schema = sf.newSchema(urlXsd);
    final Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
    final DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    final DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder(); 
    final Document doc = db.parse(path.toFile());
    validator.validate(new DOMSource(doc));
}
```

But if I use the XMLConfiguration with DefaultEntityResolver I have no success.

```
xmlConfig = new XMLConfiguration();
final URL urlXsd = getClass().getResource(SCHEMA_RESOURCE_PATH);
resolver.registerEntityId("configuration", urlXsd);
xmlConfig.setEntityResolver(resolver);
xmlConfig.setSchemaValidation(true);
```

I'm get following exception:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/.../config_default.xml; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 16; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'configuration'.
```

"configuration" is the root element of the config_default.xml. I think this means, it can't find the xsd.

My first problem, what must I put in to the first parameter of resolver.registerEntityId("configuration", urlXsd);? Waht is the public id of a schema? The [documentation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_xml.html) shows only a example with DTD public id.

Here are the reduced schema and xml -> xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
</configuration>
```

schema:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
<xs:element name="configuration">
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**UPDATE:** My test based on dbank's answer:

```
package de.company.xmlschematest;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;
import javax.xml.validation.Validator;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.XMLConfiguration;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class App
{
    private final XMLConfiguration xmlConfig = new XMLConfiguration();

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);
    private static final String CONFIG_FILENAME_DEFAULT = "config_default.xml";
    private static final String CONFIG_FILENAME_LOCAL = 
            "C:\\Data\\config_current.xml";
    private static final Path CONFIG_PATH_LOCAL = Paths.get(
            CONFIG_FILENAME_LOCAL);
    private static final String SCHEMA_FILENAME = "config_schema.xsd";
    /* package */ static final String SCHEMA_RESOURCE_PATH = "/" + SCHEMA_FILENAME;
    private static final String CONFIG_DEFAULT_RESOURCE_PATH = "/" + 
            CONFIG_FILENAME_DEFAULT;

    private static final org.apache.commons.logging.Log LOG_SEC = LogFactory.getLog(App.class);

    public App()
    {
        try
        {
            LOG_SEC.debug("JCL");

            xmlConfig.setLogger(LOG_SEC);

            final URL urlXsd = getClass().getResource(SCHEMA_RESOURCE_PATH);
            final SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
            final Schema schema = sf.newSchema(urlXsd);
            final DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            dbf.setSchema(schema);
            final DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            xmlConfig.setDocumentBuilder(db);
            xmlConfig.setSchemaValidation(true);
        }
        catch (SAXException | ParserConfigurationException ex)
        {
            LOG.error("Loading error", ex);
        }
    }


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("XmlSchemaTest started");
            final App app = new App();
            app.loadConfig();
            System.out.println("Finished");
    }

    private void loadConfig()
    {
        if(Files.exists(CONFIG_PATH_LOCAL))
        {
            try
            {
                xmlConfig.clear();
                LOG.debug("Loading config {}", CONFIG_PATH_LOCAL);
                xmlConfig.setFile(CONFIG_PATH_LOCAL.toFile());
                xmlConfig.refresh();

                LOG.info("Current config loaded");
            }
            catch (final ConfigurationException ex)
            {
                LOG.error("Loading of current config file has failed", ex);
                loadDefault();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            LOG.info("Local configuration is not available");
            loadDefault();
        }
    }

    private void loadDefault()
    {
        try
        {
            xmlConfig.clear();

            LOG.debug("Loading config " + CONFIG_FILENAME_DEFAULT);
            final File oldConfig = xmlConfig.getFile();

            xmlConfig.setURL(getClass().getResource(
                    CONFIG_DEFAULT_RESOURCE_PATH));
            if(oldConfig != null && oldConfig.exists())
            {
                oldConfig.delete();
            }

            xmlConfig.refresh();
            xmlConfig.save(CONFIG_FILENAME_LOCAL);            
            LOG.info("Default config loaded");
        }
        catch (final ConfigurationException ex)
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException("The default config file is "
                    + "not available", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have tested it with invalid xml but I see only an error in output. No exception was thrown.

```
XmlSchemaTest started
18:23:16.263 [main] DEBUG de.company.xmlschematest.App - JCL
18:23:16.325 [main] DEBUG de.company.xmlschematest.App - Loading config C:\Data\config_current.xml
18:23:16.327 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.c.ConfigurationUtils - ConfigurationUtils.locate(): base is C:\Data, name is config_current.xml
18:23:16.328 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.c.DefaultFileSystem - Could not locate file config_current.xml at C:\Data: unknown protocol: c
18:23:16.331 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.c.ConfigurationUtils - Loading configuration from the path C:\Data\config_current.xml
18:23:16.332 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.c.ConfigurationUtils - ConfigurationUtils.locate(): base is C:\Data, name is config_current.xml
18:23:16.332 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.c.DefaultFileSystem - Could not locate file config_current.xml at C:\Data: unknown protocol: c
18:23:16.332 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.c.ConfigurationUtils - Loading configuration from the path C:\Data\config_current.xml
[Error] config_current.xml:29:21: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'number'. One of '{name}' is expected
18:23:16.356 [main] INFO  de.company.xmlschematest.App - Current config loaded
Finished
```

**Update - path to xsd in xml:** 
I think a callback based handling is not so good. Based on your first suggestion I have made test with the path to xsd is in xml. But this runs only for ony trail.

```
package de.company.xmlschematest;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;
import javax.xml.validation.Validator;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.XMLConfiguration;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

/**
 *
 * @author RD3
 */
public class App
{
    private final XMLConfiguration xmlConfig = new XMLConfiguration();

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);
    private static final String CONFIG_FILENAME_DEFAULT = "config_default.xml";
    private static final String CONFIG_FILENAME_LOCAL = 
            "C:\\Data\\config_current.xml";
    private static final Path CONFIG_PATH_LOCAL = Paths.get(
            CONFIG_FILENAME_LOCAL);
    private static final String SCHEMA_FILENAME = "config_schema.xsd";
    /* package */ static final String SCHEMA_RESOURCE_PATH = "/" + SCHEMA_FILENAME;
    private static final String CONFIG_DEFAULT_RESOURCE_PATH = "/" + 
            CONFIG_FILENAME_DEFAULT;

    private static final org.apache.commons.logging.Log LOG_SEC = LogFactory.getLog(App.class);

    public App()
    {
        LOG_SEC.debug("JCL");

        xmlConfig.setLogger(LOG_SEC);
        xmlConfig.setSchemaValidation(true);
    }


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("XmlSchemaTest started");
            final App app = new App();
            app.loadConfig();
            System.out.println("Finished");
    }

    private void loadConfig()
    {
        if(Files.exists(CONFIG_PATH_LOCAL))
        {
            try
            {
                xmlConfig.clear();
                LOG.debug("Loading config {}", CONFIG_PATH_LOCAL);
                xmlConfig.setFile(CONFIG_PATH_LOCAL.toFile());
                xmlConfig.refresh();

                LOG.info("Current config loaded");
            }
            catch (final ConfigurationException ex)
            {
                LOG.error("Loading of current config file has failed", ex);
                loadDefault();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            LOG.info("Local configuration is not available");
            loadDefault();
        }
    }

    private void loadDefault()
    {
        try
        {
            xmlConfig.clear();

            LOG.debug("Loading config " + CONFIG_FILENAME_DEFAULT);
            final File oldConfig = xmlConfig.getFile();

            xmlConfig.setURL(getClass().getResource(
                    CONFIG_DEFAULT_RESOURCE_PATH));
            if(oldConfig != null && oldConfig.exists())
            {
                oldConfig.delete();
            }

            xmlConfig.refresh();
            xmlConfig.save(CONFIG_FILENAME_LOCAL);            
            LOG.info("Default config loaded");
        }
        catch (final ConfigurationException ex)
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException("The default config file is "
                    + "not available", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

The first run does process properly. It takes the xsd from jar based on xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="config_schema.xsd". Then writes the default config from loaded from jar to local filesystem. I checked the written file and can't find strange thinks. Then I make a second run of the example app, but now I get following errors:

```
XmlSchemaTest started
10:49:58.730 [main] DEBUG de.company.xmlschematest.App - JCL
10:49:58.738 [main] DEBUG de.company.xmlschematest.App - Loading config C:\Data\config_current.xml
10:49:58.740 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.c.ConfigurationUtils - ConfigurationUtils.locate(): base is C:\Data, name is config_current.xml
10:49:58.741 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.c.DefaultFileSystem - Could not locate file config_current.xml at C:\Data: unknown protocol: c
10:49:58.744 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.c.ConfigurationUtils - Loading configuration from the path C:\Data\config_current.xml
10:49:58.745 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.c.ConfigurationUtils - ConfigurationUtils.locate(): base is C:\Data, name is config_current.xml
10:49:58.745 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.c.DefaultFileSystem - Could not locate file config_current.xml at C:\Data: unknown protocol: c
10:49:58.746 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.c.ConfigurationUtils - Loading configuration from the path C:\Data\config_current.xml
10:49:58.795 [main] ERROR de.company.xmlschematest.App - Loading of current config file has failed
org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException: Error parsing file:/C:/Data/config_current.xml
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.XMLConfiguration.load(XMLConfiguration.java:1014) ~[commons-configuration-1.10.jar:1.10]
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.XMLConfiguration.load(XMLConfiguration.java:972) ~[commons-configuration-1.10.jar:1.10]
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.XMLConfiguration$XMLFileConfigurationDelegate.load(XMLConfiguration.java:1647) ~[commons-configuration-1.10.jar:1.10]
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.load(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:324) ~[commons-configuration-1.10.jar:1.10]
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.load(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:261) ~[commons-configuration-1.10.jar:1.10]
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.load(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:238) ~[commons-configuration-1.10.jar:1.10]
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.refresh(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:889) ~[commons-configuration-1.10.jar:1.10]
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractHierarchicalFileConfiguration.refresh(AbstractHierarchicalFileConfiguration.java:335) ~[commons-configuration-1.10.jar:1.10]
    at de.company.xmlschematest.App.loadConfig(App.java:110) [classes/:na]
    at de.company.xmlschematest.App.main(App.java:68) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'configuration'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1906) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:746) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:379) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:605) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3138) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:880) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.XMLConfiguration.load(XMLConfiguration.java:1006) ~[commons-configuration-1.10.jar:1.10]
    ... 9 common frames omitted
10:49:58.796 [main] DEBUG de.company.xmlschematest.App - Loading config config_default.xml
10:49:58.862 [main] INFO  de.company.xmlschematest.App - Default config loaded
Finished
```

He can't find the xsd, but the path is correct in the xml file and same like the first run. Why can he find the xsd in first fun, but not in the second run?

Second question, is that all possible log output from XMLConfiguration?

**Update 3:** I have tested again and see, If i put the xsd to local filesystem then the second run has no problems. I Think the problem is the relative search for xsd when the path is defined in xml.

Its possible to load xml from local filesystem and validate with schema located in jar file? I search a solution without callback and direct exception handling on the call of load() or refresh().

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of `resolver.registerEntityId()` is the public id used to map to a particular entity URL.  I doubt "configuration" is the correct value to use here.  However, I think that there is some confusion here and that you don't even need to bother with an Entity resolver in your case.

Say you have a mySchema.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="configuration">
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Let's say that mySchema.xml is in a jar in the `mypackage.stackoverflow` package and that jar is located at `C:\path\to\myJar.jar` (since you seem to be using Windows).  Make your your config_default.xml look something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="jar:file:/C:/path/to/myJar.jar!/mypackage/stackoverflow/mySchema.xsd">
</configuration>
```

Then you should be able to just load the config_default.xml which will reference mySchema.xsd for validation.

Using [Commons Configuration v1.10](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide_v1.10/howto_xml.html#Validation_of_XML_configuration_files):

```
XMLConfiguration config = new XMLConfiguration();
config.setFileName("config_default.xml");
config.setSchemaValidation(true);

// This will throw a ConfigurationException if the XML document does not
// conform to its Schema.
config.load();
```

**Note:** *The following turned out to not be relevant to the asker's question, but I'm leaving it here for reference.*

If you want to programmatically set the schema file, you can do so by setting the `XMLConfiguration`'s `DocumentBuilder`.

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;

import org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.XMLConfiguration;
import org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;

public class CommonsConfigTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        XMLConfiguration config = new XMLConfiguration();
        config.setFileName("config_default.xml");
        config.setSchemaValidation(true);

        try {        
            Schema schema = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI).newSchema(new File("mySchema.xsd"));
            DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            docBuilderFactory.setSchema(schema);
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            //if you want an exception to be thrown when there is invalid xml document,
            //you need to set your own ErrorHandler because the default
            //behavior is to just print an error message.
            docBuilder.setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {
                @Override
                public void warning(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
                    throw exception;
                }

                @Override
                public void error(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
                    throw exception;
                }

                @Override
                public void fatalError(SAXParseException exception)  throws SAXException {
                    throw exception;
                }  
            });
            config.setDocumentBuilder(docBuilder);
            config.load();
        } catch (ConfigurationException | ParserConfigurationException | SAXException e) {
            //handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The FileBasedConfigurationBuilder is only available in Apache Commons Configuration Version 2.x, but this version is in alpha state. I use the stable version 1.10.

Comment: @user3612610 Ah, I see.  I updated the answer to include the v1.10 example.

Comment: Thats run, but is possible to set the schema in code not in the xml file? Like my trails?

Comment: @user3612610 I added an example to show how to programmatically set the schema.

Comment: I have tested your suggestion without success. The details are available at my first post.

Comment: @user3612610 Ok, it seems you want an Exception to be thrown.  For this to happen, you need to set your own ErrorHandler on the DocumentBuilder.  I have updated the answer to show an example of such.

Comment: I think a callback based handling is not so good. I have tested with your first suggestion and added my problem to my first post :(

Comment: @user3612610: I now see that it's not the solution that you're looking for, but in general, why do you think that the callback based handling is not so good?

Comment: @user3612610 I updated the answer to show how to reference a schema in a jar file.

Comment: I have a solution for my case added to my first post. dbank thanks for your support!!!! I think the use of callback creates handling overhead based on the async processing.

Comment: @user3612610: Great! If you feel you have your own solution, please post it as a [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1):

**Solution** - for my case:

I have made a own EntityResolver that extends the DefaultEntityResolver:

```
private static class LocalSchemaResolver extends DefaultEntityResolver
    {
        @Override
        public InputSource resolveEntity(final String publicId
                , final String systemId) throws SAXException
        {
            if(systemId.endsWith(SCHEMA_FILENAME))
            {
                final InputStream stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(SCHEMA_RESOURCE_PATH);
                if(stream != null)
                {
                    final InputSource source = new InputSource(stream);
                    source.setPublicId(publicId);
                    source.setSystemId(systemId);

                    return source;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new SAXException("Schema '" + SCHEMA_FILENAME 
                            + "' is not available");
                }
            }
            return super.resolveEntity(publicId, systemId);
        }
    }
```

that maps following

```
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="config_schema.xsd"
```

to the relative path in JAR file. I can't use a absoulte path to JAR like dbank last example in my case.